# How to call child component variables inside parent component's *ngIf?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm very new on web development. I am learning Angular2 and Typescript.

I want to develop a Tab component which has 2 children components that are Header and Content. Headers are the tab headers, and contents are the contents inside these headers. I want to call tab component inside appcomponent.html as:

```
<VarTab>

 <VarTabHeader name="profile">profile</VarTabHeader>
 <VarTabHeader name="messages">messages</VarTabHeader>
 <VarTabHeader name="home">home</VarTabHeader>

 <VarTabContent name="profile">profile content</VarTabContent>
 <VarTabContent name="messages">messages content</VarTabContent>
 <VarTabContent name="home">home content</VarTabContent>

</VarTab>
```

And want to show each content inside the right header.

Here is my Header component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'VarTabHeader',
template: `
`})

export class VarTabHeader {
@Input() name:string="";

@Output() select = new EventEmitter<TabEvent>();

ngClick(){
    let event:TabEvent = new TabEvent();
    this.select.emit(event);
}
}
```

And here is my Content component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'VarTabContent',
template: `
`})

export class VarTabContent {
@Input() name:string;
}
```

Lastly, the Tab component is:

```
@Component({
selector: 'VarTab',
template: `
    activeTabNo: {{activeTabNo}}
    <div class="vartab">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" (click)="tabClicked(i)"  *ngFor="let header of headerArray; let i = index"  
                [class.active]="header.order === activeTabNo" > <a href="#">{{header.name}}</a> </li>
        </ul>

        <div *ngFor = "let content of contentArray; let i = index" > 
            <span *ngIf="content.name==='headerArray[activeTabNo].name'">{{content.name}}</span>
        </div>

    </div>
`
})

export class VarTab {
public activeTabNo:number=0;
public activeTabName:string="";
private headerArray:VarTabHeaderModel[];
private contentArray:VarTabContentModel[];


@ContentChildren(VarTabHeader) headers: QueryList<VarTabHeader>;
@ContentChildren(VarTabContent) contents: QueryList<VarTabContent>;
@Output() tabChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();

tabClicked(activeTabNo:number){
    this.activeTabNo = activeTabNo;
    this.activeTabName = this.headerArray[activeTabNo].name;
    this.tabChanged.emit(this.activeTabNo);
}

copyHeaderView(declaredHeaders:QueryList<VarTabHeader>) {
    // pushes all headers inside an array
}

copyContentView(declaredContents:QueryList<VarTabContent>) {
    // pushes all contents inside an array
}

headerOrder(key:string){
    // gives the order of header
}

initTab(){
    this.headerArray = this.copyHeaderView(this.headers);
    this.contentArray = this.copyContentView(this.contents);
}

ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.initTab();
}
}
```

Here, I manage to put all headers inside array and show them in the right order, but

```
<div *ngFor = "let content of contentArray; let i = index" > 
    <span *ngIf="content.name==='headerArray[activeTabNo].name'">{{content.name}}</span>
</div>
```

This code does not work because i and activeTabNo does not match and does not write content.name on the page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: QueryList has a `.toArray()` method, did you use thay somewhere to assign the query to an array?

Comment: And also your `export class VarTab {` is not implementing `AfterContentInit`. It should be `export class VarTab implements AfterContentInit{`

Comment: I was having sinilar issues and I had to change my `ngAftertContentInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`, because the content comes before the children view has been rendered. But `ngAfterViewInit` only fires when the children views have been loaded as well. Let me kniw which one works.

Comment: @borislemke Sorry for the late response. I handled it with `<ng-content select = VarTabContent><ng-content>`. Also even though I did not add `implements AfterContentInit`, it works fine with `ngAfterContentInit`.